# NSIS installer - change path based on dialog

Tags: nsis

Im trying to create an installer using NSIS, using "installer based on zip file".

I'd like to create a dialog box at the beginning of install that gives the user 2 choices (32, 64), then depending upon the choice they made, to change the path variable ($PROGRAMFILES32 or $PROGRAMFILES64)

Is this possible in NSIS? Are there any example scripts that could get me going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a bad idea to leave the choice to the user. I'd use the x64 headers to determine the default directory.

Include this in the header of your script.

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include x64.nsh
```

Then use this in the script, e.g. in the `.onInit` function:

```
${If} ${RunningX64}
    # 64 bit code
${Else}
    # 32 bit code
${EndIf}
```

Since you can't create a simple MessageBox with custom buttons, I'd suggest you create a dialog page with radio-buttons using [nsDialogs](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html). The `If` statement would then go to the leave function (see the [control state](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html#step-state) example), querying the value of `${NSD_GetState}`.

Comment: In this case though I dont have a choice, because I'm installing these files into a piece of software that already exists. The user might have installed the 32 or 64 bit version (they can have either, or both if they have a 64 bit computer). Any idea how to make the if/else switch work with a dialog box?

Comment: See my edited answer